# RavenDB Persisting chain of relationships

Tags: ravendb

I'm working on a collaborative document editing tool that's going to use RavenDB for persistence. In my domain I have a document class that looks like this.

```
 public class Document
{      
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IRevision CurrentRevision {get; private set; }
    public string Contents {get { return CurrentRevision.GenerateEditedContent(); }}
}
```

As you can see that document then has a CurrentRevision property that points to an IRevision object that looks like this.

```
public interface IRevision
{
    IRevision PreviousRevisionAppliedTo { get; }
    IRevision NextRevisionApplied { get; set; }
    Guid Id { get; }

    string GenerateEditedContent();
}
```

So the basic idea is that the document's contents are generated on the fly by checking out the current revision, which in turn checks it's parent revision, and so on and so forth.

Out of the box, RavenDB doesn't seem to handle persisting this chain of object references the way I need it to. I've been trying to persist it by just calling Session.Store(document), and hoping that the list of associated revisions would get stored as well. I've looked into some pieces of the RavenDB framework like custom serializers, but I can't figure out a clear path that would allow me to deserialize and reserialize the data as I would like. What's a good way to handle this situation.

Comment: How would you like this data to be stored? What would be the json format?

Comment: I guess the honest answer would be that I'm not sure. My main concern is that I can deserialize it back to the reference based linked list structure described above. I've been experimenting with using converters to build a projection that turns the linked list into an actual enumerable, but I'm not sure if this is going to make the deserialization process easier or harder. I'll edit the question to make it more clear I'm looking for guidance on the actual json format

Comment: After thinking through what my goal was and experimenting I was able to figure this out on my own. The two key pieces were making a number of fully private properties that contained the contents of the revision have public getters and having the serializer ignore the NextRevisionApplied to prevent self referencing loops. I'll post a generalized answer after some more testing.